# Filter most newest post by date in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time I post a new article I want only the newest post to be filtered and shown on my page.

However, using the code I have got is where I would like to achieve this ideally. So, essentially I will use the code I have got below twice - once to show the newest artcile as a top blog post (that will be styled differently) and then reuse this code to filter all the other posts.

Below is the code for it;

```
<article>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1 style="text-transform:uppercase;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<h4>Posted on: <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<p><?php the_content(__('Read More')); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, there are no posts available at the time.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</article>
```

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: Are you trying to get 1 blog post to be styled differently at the top of the page and the rest of them styled differently below it?

Comment: yes but have one content block solely dedicated to the newest post added then have a second content block with all the other posts

Answer (score 0):

that should be what you're looking for.

```
<!-- Start most recent post loop here -->
<?php
$query = new wp_query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '1', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );  if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Start post template here -->
<div style="padding:15px;border:1px solid red;margin-bottom:15px;"><a aria-label="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<!-- End post template here -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- End most recent post loop here -->

<!-- Start all post exept first loop here -->
<?php
$query = new wp_query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'offset' => '1' ) );  if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Start post template here -->
<div style="padding:15px;border:1px solid grey;margin-bottom:15px;"><a aria-label="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<!-- End post template here -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- End all post exept first loop here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to separately show the latest post on top styled differently and all others below it to be styled differently you can use this.

```
<article>
<?php $counter = 1; ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if($counter == 1) { ?>
<!-- Use this block to style your top most latest post -->
<h1 style="text-transform:uppercase;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<h4>Posted on: <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<p><?php the_content(__('Read More')); ?></p>
<?php $counter = $counter + 1; ?>
<!-- Top Block Ends -->
<?php } else { ?>
<!-- Use this block to style other remaining posts -->
<h1 style="text-transform:uppercase;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<h4>Posted on: <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<p><?php the_content(__('Read More')); ?></p>
<!-- Bottom Block Ends -->
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, there are no posts available at the time.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</article>
```

Change the h1 tags or style or color whatever you want for each block defined in the code and you will be able to get the desired effect.